# Elm decoding unknown json structure

Tags: json, decode, elm

I've just started working with Elm to do some front-end prototyping using a Rest API I'm working on. In general, the API returns "reasonable" data structures that can be decoded because the keys and value-types are well-known, but several resource types return a `data` entry that just has raw json that has no predetermined structure.

Everything I've read so far seems to assume you know the structure of the data you're decoding, whereas in plain js it's relatively easy to loop over the keys and reflect on the types in order to determine how they should be handled at runtime. I'm not seeing a clear path toward handling this kind of data in Elm yet.

E.g.,

```
{
  "name":"foo",
  "data": {
    "bar": [{"baz":123}, "quux"]
  },
  ...
}
```

I'd like to know if it is currently possible to parse the value of the `data` entry with something akin to

```
function go(obj)
    for key in keys(foo)
        if foo[key] is an object
            go(foo[k])
        else if foo[key] is an array
            map(go, foo[k])
        ...
```

Specifically:

1. Is it currently possible to handle unknown, possibly deeply nested and heterogeneous json data in Elm?
2. If so, can you give me the key concept or high level intuition on how the author(s) intended data like this to be decoded?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not “Elm-like” to receive a structure you don't know. In Elm, you always expect an object to contain certain properties, and Elm even does a check in run-time for whether all the properties you expect exist in that object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to write a general purpose decoder. You can first define a union type that holds all possible Json types:

```elm
type JsVal
  = JsString String
  | JsInt Int
  | JsFloat Float
  | JsArray (List JsVal)
  | JsObject (Dict String JsVal)
  | JsNull
```

And now you can use `Json.Decode.oneOf` to try every possibility.

```elm
import Json.Decode as D exposing (Decoder)
import Dict exposing (Dict)

jsValDecoder : Decoder JsVal
jsValDecoder =
  D.oneOf
    [ D.string |> D.andThen (D.succeed << JsString)
    , D.int |> D.andThen (D.succeed << JsInt)
    , D.float |> D.andThen (D.succeed << JsFloat)
    , D.list (D.lazy (\_ -> jsValDecoder)) |> D.andThen (D.succeed << JsArray)
    , D.dict (D.lazy (\_ -> jsValDecoder)) |> D.andThen (D.succeed << JsObject)
    , D.null JsNull
    ]
```

[`Json.Decode.lazy`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Json-Decode#lazy) is necessary for the `JsArray` and `JsObject` constructors because they are defined recursively.

This structure should handle anything you throw at it, and it will be up to the rest of your program to decide what to do with such a flexible type.

**Edit**

As @Tosh pointed out, this decoder can be cleaned up by using `map` instead of an `andThen` followed by a `succeed`:

```elm
jsValDecoder : Decoder JsVal
jsValDecoder =
  D.oneOf
    [ D.map JsString D.string
    , D.map JsInt D.int
    , D.map JsFloat D.float
    , D.list (D.lazy (\_ -> jsValDecoder)) |> D.map JsArray
    , D.dict (D.lazy (\_ -> jsValDecoder)) |> D.map JsObject
    , D.null JsNull
    ]
```

Comment: Just want to comment that you could use a form: e.g. `D.map JsString D.string`.  A little bit easier to read for me, at least.

Comment: Thanks, @Tosh! Good point, A single cased `success` monadic bind is a good smell that a simple `map` should work just as well.

Answer (score 4):

In [Chad's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34409/chad-gilbert) excellent answer, the boolean type is missing. Here's a full module able to handle booleans as well:

```
module Data.JsonValue exposing (JsonValue(..), decoder)

import Dict exposing (Dict)
import Json.Decode as Decode
    exposing
        ( Decoder
        , dict
        , string
        , int
        , float
        , list
        , null
        , oneOf
        , lazy
        , map
        , bool
        )


type JsonValue
    = JsonString String
    | JsonInt Int
    | JsonFloat Float
    | JsonBoolean Bool
    | JsonArray (List JsonValue)
    | JsonObject (Dict String JsonValue)
    | JsonNull


decoder : Decoder JsonValue
decoder =
    oneOf
        [ map JsonString string
        , map JsonInt int
        , map JsonFloat float
        , map JsonBoolean bool
        , list (lazy (\_ -> decoder)) |> map JsonArray
        , dict (lazy (\_ -> decoder)) |> map JsonObject
        , null JsonNull
        ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how to use it? Could you provide an example? I mean I have that data, but how to build HTML with that data?